# Immersed in real-world challenges, I never stop thinking how to make our world better.[Is this correct]

Tags: dependent-clause, independent-clauses

I've been asked to proofread an essay which consists of tons of these kind of twisted sentences. My question are whether this sentence is correct and in what case should there be a verb at the 'naked' sentence(clause?). Is there a way to test this that works every time? If this sentence is correct would the first clause change in past tense?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The sentence looks twisted?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, grammatically.

Comment: by twisted i mean there is no subject in the first clause and you could easily put this statement behind the subject after the comma. Doesn't feel natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Immersed in real-world challenges, I never stop thinking how to make our world better.//
Passive participial phrase, preceding the independent clause.  Here, the tense is decided by the independent clause, and not the phrase. Common subject is 'I'.

This is a simple sentence, the complex form of which could be, say, "Though I am immersed in real-world challenges, I never stop.....". This structure is common in serious writing, but too much of it will kill the beauty of writing.

It can even be interpreted in a different way, that is: "Being immersed in real-world challenges, I never stop....", or "Having been immersed in real-world challenges, I never stop..."

Comment: Wow, the name of this thing has been grinding my gears for so long, thaaaank you, upped. So this is correct? Is this often used in official texts and applications?
https://grammarwritingrevision.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/verbal-phrases-participles-and-participial-phrases/
On this website i found that tenses don't matter(?) and also that if my original sentence is an active present continous one then i should make the pass. participle sentence using v+ing. I am a bit confused.